# Aggregate unique values from multiple columns with pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique, pandas-groupby

I went into countless threads ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434426/pandas-groupby-unique-multiple-columns) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106490/how-to-get-unique-values-from-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-groupby) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556165/how-can-i-drop-duplicate-data-in-a-single-column-group-wise-in-pandas)...) and still I don't find a solution to my problem...
I have a dataframe like this:

```
prop1 prop2 prop3    prop4 
L30   3     bob      11.2
L30   54    bob      10
L30   11    john     10
L30   10    bob      10
K20   12    travis   10 
K20   1     travis   4 
K20   66    leo      10
```

I would like to do a groupby on prop1, AND at the same time, get all the other columns aggregated, but only with unique values. Like that:

```
prop1  prop2       prop3       prop4
L30    3,54,11,10  bob,john    11.2,10
K20    12,1,66     travis,leo  10,4
```

I tried with different methods:

1. `df.groupby('prop1')['prop2','prop3','prop4'].apply(np.unique)`
   returns

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
>   PLUS TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type

2. Also: `.apply(lambda x: pd.unique(x.values.ravel()).tolist())` which gives a list as output, and I would like columns.
3. `df.groupby('prop1')['prop2','prop3','prop4'].unique()` by itself doesn't work because there are multiple columns.
4. `.apply(f)` with f being:

   `def f(df):
      df['prop2']=df['prop2'].drop_duplicates()
      df['prop3']=df['prop3'].drop_duplicates()
      df['prop4']=df['prop4'].drop_duplicates()
      return df`

doesn't do anything.

5. I also tried to use `.agg()` with different options but didn't get success.

Does one of you would have any idea?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: (I had a small intro with 'Hello guys, I'm using pandas' etc... But it was deleted by a wrong copy and paste when reformatting, sorry... :) )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `agg`, and aggregate only unique values by calling `Series.unique`:

```
df.astype(str).groupby('prop1').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique()))

            prop2       prop3      prop4
prop1                                   
K20       12,1,66  travis,leo   10.0,4.0
L30    3,54,11,10    bob,john  11.2,10.0
```

---

```
df.astype(str).groupby('prop1', sort=False).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique()))

            prop2       prop3      prop4
prop1                                   
L30    3,54,11,10    bob,john  11.2,10.0
K20       12,1,66  travis,leo   10.0,4.0
```

---

If handling NaNs is important, call `fillna` in advance:

```
import re
df.fillna('').astype(str).groupby('prop1').agg(
    lambda x: re.sub(',+', ',', ','.join(x.unique()))
)

            prop2       prop3      prop4
prop1                                   
K20       12,1,66  travis,leo   10.0,4.0
L30    3,54,11,10    bob,john  11.2,10.0
```

Comment: I already found the Series.unique but I was still mentionning all the columns, which was blocking it to work I assume.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked for me perfectly:

```
df.groupby(['prop1','prop2', 'prop4']).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())).reset_index()
```

This will give the result as:

```
prop1  prop2       prop3       prop4
L30    3,54,11,10  bob,john    11.2,10
K20    12,1,66     travis,leo  10,4
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `melt` + `pivot_table`

```
s = df.astype(str).melt(id_vars='prop1').drop_duplicates()

s.pivot_table(
  index='prop1',
  columns='variable',
  values='value',
  aggfunc=','.join)
```

```
variable       prop2       prop3      prop4
prop1
K20          12,1,66  travis,leo   10.0,4.0
L30       3,54,11,10    bob,john  11.2,10.0
```